# basemap scatterplot colour based on dataframe column value

Tags: python, data-visualization, visualization, scatter-plot, matplotlib-basemap

I have geographical data that I would like to plot on a map. I have latitude, longitude and I also have another column in my dataframe that is gender of a person.

Now I would like to plot a red dot if my person is Male and a Green dot if the person is Female.

I am able to plot a single colour, but unable to add a condition based on dataframe column. Following is my code

```
m = Basemap(projection='merc',
             llcrnrlat=15,  #latitude of lower left hand corner of the desired map domain
             urcrnrlat=55, #latitude of upper right hand corner of the desired map domain
             llcrnrlon=75, #longitude of lower left hand corner of the desired map domain
             urcrnrlon=135, #longitude of upper right hand corner of the desired map domain
             lat_ts=0, #latitude of true scale
             resolution='c') #resolution of boundary dataset being used - c for crude


m.fillcontinents(color='#191919',lake_color='#000000') # dark grey land, black lakes
m.drawmapboundary(fill_color='#000000')                # black background
m.drawcountries(linewidth=0.15, color="w")              # thin white line for country borders

# Plot the data
mxy = m(dfPerson["longitude"].tolist(), dfPerson["latitude"].tolist())
m.scatter(mxy[0], mxy[1], s=5, c='#ff0000', zorder=2)
plt.title("China Map")
plt.show()
```

Is there a way, I can set the colour c = '#ff0000# or '#00ff00# based on dfPerson['gender'] == 'Male' or not ?

And if I had to choose multiple conditions like Male, Female, RatherNotSay and 3 different colours ?

Comment: I solved it myself by splitting the dataframe rows based on the filter and by adding a second m.scatter statement with a different colour.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it myself by splitting the dataframe rows based on filters. So instead of a single dataframe, I had as many for the variants I needed. And passed the dataframes to individual m.Scatter function calls with different colours.

It solved the problem.